# problematic results after Elastic Search upgrade

Tags: json, grails, elasticsearch, render

I've updated my Elastic Search from 0.19.4 to 0.20.6 and I'm not getting the desired results.. I'm doing a dynamic search after key presses and the code that was working fine before acts different now.

The Search:

```
'' = (empty field) fine
a = 9400 hits
ab = 126 hits ERROR
abc = 2 hits ERROR
abcd 0 hits fine
```

Dependencies I've changed:

```
runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-lang-groovy:1.1.0' --> runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-lang-groovy:1.3.0'
runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.19.4' --> runtime 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.20.6'
runtime 'org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.0.4.1' (new)
```

Stack:

```
2013-04-09 10:47:58,130 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG xxxx.SearchController  - result stuff is: [hits:org.elasticsearch.search.internal.InternalSearchHits@9b0d61b]
2013-04-09 10:47:58,137 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR xxxx.SearchController  - Problem...
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class org.elasticsearch.search.internal.InternalSearchHit
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:134)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:150)
    at xxx.xxxx.xxxx.SearchController.autocomplete(SearchController.groovy:514)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.lzf.LZFCompressor.isCompressed(LZFCompressor.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.compressor(CompressorFactory.java:124)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.compress.CompressorFactory.uncompressIfNeeded(CompressorFactory.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.internal.InternalSearchHit.sourceRef(InternalSearchHit.java:172)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.internal.InternalSearchHit.getSourceRef(InternalSearchHit.java:181)
    ... 13 more
```

Where the code fails:

```
try {
            log.debug("result stuff is: ${results}");
            render results as JSON
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            log.error("Problem...",e);
        }
```

Comment: It seems like the render to JSON doesn't recognize one of the returned parameters by the new ES..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a slight change in ES structure, had to rewrite my conversion method :)